# Why it only add the number with += and not +

Tags: javascript, numbers, addition

I am learning to code and trying out some JavaScript programming and came across this which I don't understand. Please help!
I don't understand why it wouldn't add the number with '+' but does with '+='.

```
let number = 10;
number + 10; //Return 10
number += 10; //Return 20
console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an important distinction to make between and ***expression*** and an ***instruction***. An *expression* evaluates to a value, but doesn't necessarily have an effect. An *instruction* doesn't necessarily evaluate to a value, but has some effect.

In your example, `number + 10` is an expression that evaluates to `20`. But it has no effect by itself.

By contrast, `number += 10` is an instruction that modifies the value of variable `number`.

Note that `number += 10` is essentially equivalent to `number = number + 10`.

The last line in your code, `console.log(number)`, is also an instruction: it prints the value of `number`.

Have you tried the instruction `console.log(number + 10)`?

Comment: @NickParsons I debated with myself how formal a definition of "expression" and "instruction" I should give. I decided to go for the intuition. An instruction does something, and an expression evaluates to something. That's very informal and reality is a lot more complex - an instruction contains an expression, and an expression contains sub-expressions. If a beginner isn't understanding the difference between `number + 10` and `number += 10` yet, I don't think they even *need* to know that `number += 10` actually evaluates to a value. In most cases that value is going to be discarded anyway.

Comment: I agree with that, I think your edit now also makes things clearer/more correct now. Nice explanation also

Answer (score 0):

'+=' operator come from C language
and it's a shortcut for

```
number = number + 10
```

so in your code all works,
but `number + 10` is just operation without assignment;

Answer (score 0):

The line `number + 10` will calculate the value but you need to assign this value to the variable (to store it in the variable).

Indeed, you need to write `number = number + 10`.

About the syntax `+=` : It only makes the code easier to read, the two following make exactly the same thing :

- `number = number + 10`
- `number += 10`

For more informations [Addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)